# Adding three filter conditions pulled from another sheet to pull a result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am hoping to add get a result based on three conditions pulled from another Sheet on Google Sheets. I can figure out how to add two conditions but when I add the third it doesn't retrieve a result or an error.

Sheet 1 - Task Status

Sheet 2 - Team 1 | Week Overview

Sheet 3 - Team 2 | Week Overview

Task Status holds all of the tasks for the project which are assigned to a specific team. Sheet 2 and 3 show the only the tasks assigned for that team, and what day they are due. The final column shows the task that has been completed that week.

The formula I have is `=IFERROR(FILTER('Task Status'!$E7:$E, 'Task Status'!$D7:$D=H$3,'Task Status'!$H7:$H=B$3, 'Task Status'!$G7:$G<>'Task Status'!B$3))`

But `Task Status'!$D7:$D=H$3` is not pulling the tasks only for that Team. Without it, the formula works as it should.

Find the Google Sheet example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-wgVzY6K-V1qj4vNmrbFYwaoF1HJldTkscxwDMcL6AY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell A4 of sheet 'Team 1 | Weekly Overview' I entered

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Task Status'!$E$7:$E, 'Task Status'!$D$7:$D=$A$1, 'Task Status'!$H$7:$H=A$3, 'Task Status'!$G$7:$G<>'Task Status'!$B$3))
```

and filled to the right.

The cell H$3 you were referring to, had no value.

I also changed the formula in F4 to

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Task Status'!$E7:$E, 'Task Status'!D7:$D=$A$1,'Task Status'!$G7:$G='Task Status'!B$3))
```

See if that helps?